# Making non-alcoholic sparkling cider

Tags: fruit

We are looking for the amount of potassium sorbate required for the shelf life of sparkling apple cider.  We have a local brewery carbinating it for us. 
We are filtering it with a maple syrup plate press....
We are looking to bottle thursday.

Comment: The brewers at the brewery doing the carbonation for you don't have the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Fresh cider that is not pasteurized, treated with UV light, or another sterilization method can have wild yeast and bacteria present. These microbes can spoil your cider.

Potassium sorbate is used to prevent yeast from reproducing. By itself, it does not kill yeast or bacteria. Potassium metabisulfite should be used in addition to produce a stable cider.

Dosages vary, but typically 1 tsp of potassium sorbate and 1/2 tsp of potassium metabisulfite per 5 gallons is sufficient. Some recommendations call for 1-1/2 tsp potassium sorbate and 2/3 tsp potassium metabisulfite per 5 gallons.

Review the following links for more explanation:

[Winemaker's Academy - Potassium Sorbate](http://www.google.com/url?url=http://winemakersacademy.com/potassium-sorbate-wine-making/&rct=j&frm=1&q=&esrc=s&sa=U&ei=e6dGVLr-G8iPsQS_nYKACw&ved=0CBYQFjAA&sig2=k8eXqIS94o-_i5tVc9sZDg&usg=AFQjCNGQFiBgmx-GCobI2l8uxoJUkq1qIQ)

[Winemaker's Academy - Metabisulphite](http://www.google.com/url?url=http://winemakersacademy.com/potassium-metabisulfite-wine/&rct=j&frm=1&q=&esrc=s&sa=U&ei=e6dGVLr-G8iPsQS_nYKACw&ved=0CBwQFjAB&sig2=sz5FoBgYQLZjWhfZKuVThA&usg=AFQjCNGKmt9lRonb15LLfSoYXG8-TqPlYA)